# C++ copy stream manipulator to other stream

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stream

Imagine a `std::ostream& operator<<` wants to do some stuff with numbers. For this purpose, someone might want to use `std::hex`, some other may want to use none, whatever, any manipulator is possible.

How could I copy those to another `std::ostream` without the text-content of the `ostream` passed as argument? I need the manipulators *only*.

So I want that `std::cout << std::hex << someCoolClass(10)`, where `someCoolClass` could look like

```
struct someCoolClass
{
    someCoolClass(int i) : _i(i)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const someCoolClass& rhs)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        //magically copy manipulators of os
        ss << _i;
        return os << ss.str();
    }
private:
    int _i;
};
```

prints `a`. I know this example is useless and especially the other stream to convert the integer to a string seems to be useless but lets imagine that this isn't useless and not pure nonsene.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ios::copyfmt`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/copyfmt/)

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const someCoolClass& rhs)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.copyfmt(os);        // <- copy formatting
    ss << rhs._i;
    return os << ss.str();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8c1c6d74e6e53fe)